# Cap staging deploy doesn't replace image-url("/assets/logo_white.png") with the fingerprinted image file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running a rails site which has a capistrano deployment process. I understand a bit about the deployment pipeline and how static files are served directly from Nginx. However it was my understanding that static image file links should get updated to reflect the new fingerprinted image filename.

For example, after deployment, my file logo_white gets placed in the public/assets folder and the new filename becomes:

```
logo_white-204b61bda69f4aae0c9bb35ca909cdc2.png
```

However, in my application.css.scss file, the line:

```
image-url("/assets/logo_white.png");
```

Gets turned into

```
url(/assets/logo_white.png)
```

That's not right. How do I instruct the sass compiler to use the new fingerprinted image name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `image-url` helper method in your SASS stylesheet, you don't want to include the /assets/ part of the path. Just the name of the image should suffice.

```
image-url("logo_white.png");
```

Also, even though your assets are compiled, make sure that your application is actually running in the `production` environment.